# D3.js crashes IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js

Although this will be a vague question, I can't seem to find an answer to the problem and hope you can help me out.

I have a leaflet map where D3.js shows some information (circles and arrows) on. The information comes from the backend and is processed in the frontend before drawing it on the screen. It runs just fine on chrome and Firefox only IE crashes (without given any information why). I debugged my JavaScript code and it seems that IE crashes after my function is executed. That brings me to the presumption that it probably will be a rendering issue. So I checked the memory usage in IE using the debugger tools but nothing seems off. Even after the crash the memory still measures a low amount of usage. I'm running out of ideas to figure this one out, is there anyone that can suggest another approach or can suggest me how to narrow the problem down?

Comment: I guess nobody can help you to solve the issue without a source code of the application you're talking about ) I may recommend basic ideas... Just refactor the code, remove unnecessary functions/objects, take a look on memory leaks and so on. Here you may find useful recommendations https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript

Comment: _"IE crashes after my function is executed"_ yes... thats vague.  What function??  ...What version oF IE?

Comment: svg is not supported for all browsers... try to take a look at [this](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) library

Answer (score 0):

Why d3 won't work well with Internet Explorer

1) d3 outputs SVG (scaleable vector graphics) markup to be interpreted by the browser. Internet Explorer 8 and below, do not recognize SVG, but rather VML (Vector Markup Lanuage).

2) The d3 javascript library currently contains some javascript which cause errors with IE8 and below.

3) Many of the examples online of using d3 contains javascript which causes errors with Internet Explorer.

for Detail refer [this](http://jeffpflueger.com/content/d3-data-driven-documents-and-internet-explorer)

*Also mention in which ie version u got problem.*

Comment: Here is the [link](http://jeffpflueger.com/content/d3-data-driven-documents-and-internet-explorer). please check